# Custom Validation of HTTP Authorization header in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, authorization

There are multiple REST APIs exposed in my spring boot application. Some of these APIs require Authorization and some doesn't. Authorization is being done using the HTTP Authorization header.

Is there some way in Spring boot using Annotations or any other simpler way to do Authorization on few of the REST APIs and skip others?

Things tried and worked but not satisfactory.

1) Filter - URI configuration - explicitly added uris to filter/skip.

2) Manual validation in each of the rest api controller method.

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you provide code?

Comment: Check Spring Boot security samples: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-method-security/src/main/java/sample/security/method/SampleMethodSecurityApplication.java . Spring security expressions: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-expressions-basic . You can configure which URL / methods require authentication and what rights.

Comment: And Spring Security Architecture: https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture/

Comment: Why not using Spring Security? I've achieved this easily using `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter` and posted sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52443974/spring-security-cannot-permit-request-in-custom-fiter) (yes, answered my own question XD)