# Spring security. Cannot permit request in custom fiter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to implement authorization with a specific header (say "sessionId") and secure all uri's except one.

I extended `OncePerRequestFilter` and implemented custom `AuthenticationProvider` to check if sessionId is valid (as well as custom Token class etc).

How it works now: for **any** uri it immediately jumps to `AuthSessionAuthenticationProvider`'s `authenticate` method right after `AuthSessionFilter` is applied and returns 403 if header `sessionId` isn't specified. But I want some uri's to allow access without that header.

It all together:

config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(permittedUris).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AuthSessionAccessDeniedHandler())
                .and().addFilterBefore(new AuthSessionFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Filter:

```
public class AuthSessionFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        Authentication auth = new AuthSessionToken(request.getHeader("sessionId"));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Provider:

```
public class AuthSessionAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    //...

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        AuthSessionToken token = (AuthSessionToken) authentication;

        if (token.getSessionId() == null) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Missing header sessionId");
        }

        AuthSessionAuthorities user = authSessionService.getUserAuthoritiesToken(token.getSessionId());

        if (user == null) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Session ID invalid: " + token.getSessionId());
        }

        token.setAuthenticatedUser(user);
        return token;
    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: The best way to do is to filter out the requests that don't need to have that request and skip the AuthSessionFilter for those but, if you need that every request goes through your filter, then you should check the request inside AuthSessionFilter.doFilterInternal to see if it needs the sessionId header. In case it does not need it, initialize an Authentication object that has a token so it can bypass the AuthSessionAuthenticationProvider

Comment: Could you please explain, I don't need every request pass through filter, only those that need to be authenticated..

Comment: What is the value of permittedUris? Do the requests that don't need to be authenticated match permittedUris?

Comment: @JaviMollá Sure. Say its `"/do-job"`. But this uri needs sessionId header now((

Comment: With your configuration, you're saying that /do-job request does not have to go through the filter, isn't it?

Comment: @JaviMollá Yes. And I understand this :) Just don't know how to achieve this) Should I check the uri in a filter by hand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180525/discussion-between-daria-and-javi-molla).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more elegant solution that was developed exactly for that purpose.
It's a `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter`. And then `antMatchers` works as expected. The initial configuration looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    @SneakyThrows
    public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter preAuthenticationFilter() {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter preAuthenticationFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        preAuthenticationFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(SESSION_ID);
        preAuthenticationFilter.setCredentialsRequestHeader(SESSION_ID);
        preAuthenticationFilter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
        preAuthenticationFilter.setContinueFilterChainOnUnsuccessfulAuthentication(true);
        preAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());

        return preAuthenticationFilter;
    }
```